# Undefined behavior for sending a std::vector<object of user-defined class> in MPI

Tags: c++, mpi, stdvector, user-defined-types

Following tutorials over registering a new type of MPI, I've registered my simple class of having two members using `MPI_Type_create_struct`. The problem is that if the size of `std::vector` grows to 20000 - (this's of course vary system by system depending on available stack size), I'll get :

```
 Read -1, expected 800000, errno = 14
 Read -1, expected 800000, errno = 14
*** Process received signal ***
Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
```

For smaller size, the code goes well. Based on changing class definition and adding more members of larger size, I can see why this is happening, but don't know how to resolve it. For example, If I add an array of size of 1000 as the member of this class whether as static array or `std::vector`, I couldn't allocate `std::vector<Dummy>` for 2 millions serially. Precisely, `std::vector<Dummy> TobeSend  (containerSize, Dummy(target))` will throw `std::bad_alloc` when running only with one processor.
I think the issue is having `std::vector<Dummy>` as a buffer to send, the usual best practise is having `std::vector<*Dummy>` , but since this's MPI, using pointers won't work. I'd appreciate ideas over this.

```
#include <mpi.h> 
#include <vector>
#include <stddef.h> 
#include <assert.h>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std; 
typedef int64_t emInt;
class Dummy
{
private:
    emInt N ; 
    emInt Array[2][2]; 
public:
    
    Dummy(const int64_t nDivs) : 
    N(nDivs)
    {

    };
    friend MPI_Datatype register_mpi_type(Dummy const&); 
    ~Dummy() {}; 
};

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);     
    int rank , size ;
    int tag=0 ; 
    int flag=0 ;   
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Request request;
    MPI_Status status;
    Dummy object (1); 
    MPI_Datatype dummyType = register_mpi_type(object);

    std::size_t containerSize = 20000;  

    std::vector<int> neighbrs = {0, 1, 2, 3};
    for(auto itri:neighbrs)
    {
        int target = itri; 
        if(rank!= target)
        {
            std::vector<Dummy> TobeSend  (containerSize, Dummy(target)); 
            MPI_Isend(TobeSend.data(),containerSize,dummyType,
          target, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request ) ; 
            
        }

    }
    for(auto isource:neighbrs)
    {
        int source = isource;
        if(rank!= source)
        {
            std::vector<Dummy> TobeRecvd (containerSize ,Dummy(0));
            MPI_Irecv(TobeRecvd.data(),containerSize, dummyType ,source,tag,
            MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request); 
        }
    }
    MPI_Finalize(); 
    return 0; 
}

MPI_Datatype register_mpi_type(Dummy const&)
{
    Dummy object(1);

    MPI_Datatype builtType;

    constexpr std::size_t numMembers = 2;

    MPI_Datatype types[numMembers]=
    {
        MPI_INT64_T,
        MPI_INT64_T
    }
    ;

    int arrayOfBlockLengths[numMembers];

    arrayOfBlockLengths[0] = 1; 
    arrayOfBlockLengths[1] = 4; 

    MPI_Aint baseadress ; 

    MPI_Aint arrayOfDisplacements [numMembers] 
    = 
    {
        offsetof (Dummy,N),
        offsetof (Dummy,Array),
    };
    MPI_Type_create_struct(numMembers,arrayOfBlockLengths,arrayOfDisplacements,types,&builtType);
    MPI_Type_commit(&builtType);
    return builtType; 
};
```

**CallStack:**

```
 #0  0x00007ffff7b6e94d in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff4d0b244 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/openmpi3/mca_btl_vader.so
#2  0x00007ffff4769556 in mca_pml_ob1_send_request_schedule_once () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/openmpi3/mca_pml_ob1.so
#3  0x00007ffff4767811 in mca_pml_ob1_recv_frag_callback_ack () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/openmpi3/mca_pml_ob1.so
#4  0x00007ffff4d0fae5 in mca_btl_vader_poll_handle_frag () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/openmpi3/mca_btl_vader.so
#5  0x00007ffff4d0fdb1 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/openmpi3/mca_btl_vader.so
#6  0x00007ffff7942714 in opal_progress () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopen-pal.so.40
#7  0x00007ffff7e9fc0d in ompi_mpi_finalize () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpi.so.40
#8  0x000055555555dd9c in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffd438) at classicDataType.cpp:159
```

Comment: errno = 14 is EFAULT which means you are passing a bad address to a system call. There should be no problem with allocating objects like you describe unless you are running a 32 bit program. If you get a `bad_alloc` from a vector constructor, isolate the case and create a [mcve].

Comment: "The problem is that if the size of std::vector grows to 20000" Are you sure you're not just running out of memory? What makes you think this is caused by something like undefined behavior?

Comment: @Chipster Okay, maybe it's my bad to see this as undefined behaviour. But, if we are running out of memory to do this, why is that? And how to prevent that when I don't have any choice to use pointers to my object?

Comment: @n.m.willseey'allonReddit I did my best to isolate the problem and make it small, so it will be reproducible. What do you mean unless I'm running on 32 bit program?

Comment: @n.m.willseey'allonReddit Okay I see what you meant by isolating the problem, I want to make a new question for that part of bad allocation I explain sine it won't involve any MPI stuff.

Comment: I'm not really sure. I did the math for the code sample you gave and it shouldn't be as huge as I originally thought. That said, the fact that this seems to work with smaller sizes says to me it's at least a possibility that you're running out of memory. But it obviously depends on the system you're using and stuff like that.

Comment: Are you compiling for a 32-bit architecture with a 32-bit compiler?

Comment: Note: the OP later asked [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76701266/22081063) about something similar.

Comment: @n.m.willseey'allonReddit The architecture is 64-bit but not sure how to check whether the compiler is 32-bit or 64-bit

Comment: `request` is overwritten and you never `MPI_Wait()` on it. try with something simpler with 2 MPI tasks: one sender, one receiver and use blocking subroutines.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Yes, with two processors everything is fine. I want exactly to be able to have non-blocking and this is what it fails, I'm going to open a new question with this regard just sending an array of integers that fail. My suspicion is that something happens with multiple processors at the same time want to allocate memory to handle send/recv

Comment: you are issuing multiple `irecv()` on the **same** buffer, so at the end it will be anarchy.
what if you `MPI_Recv()` and check the content of the buffer before moving to the next iteration? An other option is to `MPI_Irecv()` on **diferent** buffers and then `MPI_Waitall()`.

Comment: I can't do MPI_Recv (), the real program hangs up due to the size of the problem and work involved. Wht do you mean by MPI_Irecv() on different buffers? Isn't the case that everyone will have a separate copy of TobeRecvd?

Comment: you cannot have two pending `MPI_Irecv()` on the same buffer. So either use several buffers, or one `MPI_Irecv()` at a time (which is pretty much equivalent to `MPI_Recv()` here)

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Thanks a lot, it's very good point. In fact, I think type serialization here is no problem, since I can take the same behaviour when trying to only have primitve types. Then, I think your point is the cause of issue