# How to properly allocate memory for std::vector of a class having relatively large array as member

Tags: c++, memory, vector

I'm defining a class having 2 and 3 D arrays that I'm trying to declare them as the `std::vector` rather than static arrays.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#define MAX_DIVS 50

class Dummy
{
private:
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> array; 

    //double m_param_st[MAX_DIVS + 1][MAX_DIVS + 1][2];
    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>> m_param_st;
public:
    Dummy() 
    {
        array.resize(MAX_DIVS+1);
        for(auto i=0 ; i<MAX_DIVS+1 ; i++)
        {
            array[i].resize(MAX_DIVS+1); 
        }
        
        m_param_st.resize(MAX_DIVS + 1);
        for (auto i = 0; i < MAX_DIVS + 1; i++)
        {
            m_param_st[i].resize(MAX_DIVS + 1);
            for (auto j = 0; j < MAX_DIVS + 1; j++)
            {
                m_param_st[i][j].resize(2);
            }
        }
    }
    ~Dummy() {}; 
};


int main(int argc, char* const argv[]) 
{
    
    std::size_t size = 100000;  
    std::vector<Dummy> Temp1 (size, Dummy() ); 
    return 0; 
}
```

later, I need to have `std::vector` of my objects, but it hangs up for only 100000 (definitely, at which point crashes depend on available stack size and it varies system by system) of objects and sometimes, it throws std::bad_alloc.

Obviously, if instead I define `std::vector<Dummy*>`, I won't have this problem, but I have constraints not to do that and only have static allocation of objects inside `std::vector`.

Comment: FYI -- This has nothing to do with the stack, as vector allocates all memory dynamically.  Second, the `Dummy` constructor need not have any `for` loops:  [See this](https://godbolt.org/z/hj9obW3q5).

Comment: *Obviously, if instead I define std::vector<Dummy*>, I won't have this problem* -- You still have to allocate all of the memory, whether it is by using `new`, or have `std::vector` do it.  So you're in all likelihood making the problem worse, not better, by using `std::vector<Dummy*>`.  Maybe if you describe on a high-level what problem you are trying to solve, then maybe alternatives will be suggested.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie at high level, I will have larger std::vector in order of millions. and the real class will have more members like this and then I need to communicate this data in MPI

Comment: Do you have any idea how much memory you are trying to allocate in this example? It runs for me, but it is > 50gb.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Can I ask why the way that I'm resizing is wrong? And constructor should not have for loop?

Comment: @RetiredNinja Not sure how to know that? sizeof?

Comment: @MA19 -- You do see that the code I posted does exactly what you are trying to do?  The `std::vector` class can be initialized in the member-initialization list by using the appropriate `std::vector` constructor, and not have to write `for` loops to resize all the elements manually.

Comment: FWIW, the constructor can be "simplified" to be `Dummy() : array(std::vector{MAX_DIVS + 1, std::vector{MAX_DIVS + 1, 0}}), m_param_st(std::vector{MAX_DIVS + 1, std::vector{MAX_DIVS + 1, std::vector{2, 0.0}}}) {}`

Comment: I check the code that @PaulMcKenzie  wrote and worked, but why my way of doing is that wrong?

Comment: @MA19 -- It isn't "wrong".  The way you've done it is not recommended.  First, the entire vector in my example (and the one NathanOliver posted) is actually *initialized* with *all* the information.  Your version 1) initializes the vector to empty and then in the constructor body, *assigns* the vector with the values, and 2) Your method is error prone and more than likely thwarts any optimizations that the optimizer may be able to perform.

Comment: @MA19 *I will have larger std::vector in order of millions.* -- I know this -- you are stating your solution, and trying to make your solution work.  What I am asking is what problem are you really trying to solve?  This is more like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @RetiredNinja -- As an observation, godbolt gives a SIGKILL when running with 100000.  Reduce the number, and the program goes through.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The class is in fact the data structure for a triangular face and although here I could have the size of parameters and array fixed in advance, the better way for me is having that determined at run time when I pass an integer to the constructor to initialize the sizes for me. I have several constructors that one of them accepts an intger for doing that

Comment: @MA19 -- Well, you do see that your solution is not feasible for environments that do not have many gigabytes of memory, as pointed out by RetiredNinja.  Is this your intention, to have your program only run on very high-end systems with gigantic amounts of memory?  If not, then you need to consider a different design, which may or may not be trivial.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Oh I mistakenly thought that way of initialization had solved my problem for large (only, 100000), but I was testing the wrong code. So, It has not changed anything on my side

Comment: I don't understand why, 100000 is large here in this simple example and can't go through. Maybe, changing that to millions will be my tomorrow's problem but for now, I think, 100000 is still decent

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Is this your intention, to have your program only run on very high-end systems with gigantic amounts of memory? no

Comment: @MA19 The question is does the computer you are running this on have the necessary resources available for what you are trying to allocate? If not then it makes perfect sense that it fails.

Comment: @MA19 -- Well, you can state in your release notes "limited by available memory" (the simple way out of this scenario), or you have some sort of file caching going on (the smarter, but more involved way).  Your application is no different than Notepad trying to load files in the multiple gigabyte size category and failing due to low memory, and a commercial grade text editor that has been specially built for huge files -- it takes work to create the latter.

Comment: @Retired Ninja How to check that? my RAM is 16 GB

Comment: @MA19 Then it's simple, you do not have enough memory on your system. Nothing to do with stack or heap. Now computers use *paging* to make it seem like they have more memory than they do but you are a long long way short of your requirements,

Comment: @MA19 -- What is the final result of all of these vectors you are saying you are processing?  If the final result is just a few vectors, or even just a few numbers, stats, etc. then the usual way this is done is to cache the intermediate results of, maybe 1000 vectors at a time, to disk, and do the computations a little more smartly.  Then of course, you have to write the code to recall already computed items from the disk cache when necessary.  How did ancient computers from the 1990's able to display gigantic bitmaps where the user is allowed to scroll up and down with little RAM memory?

Comment: One simple (although rather slow) way to solve your problem would be to add a few hundred gigabytes of swap space to your computer (or actual RAM, but that's more expensive). Or maybe find a way to not require so much memory at the same time and do things in smaller chunks.

Comment: Possibly relevant is [the OP's previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76699486/22081063) on something similar.

Comment: I will renew my comments there that I still think you might just be running out of memory. Whatever algorithm you're doing, you're allocating too much for the system you're on.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an explicit constructor and a destructor.

```
class Dummy
{
private:
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> array{MAX_DIVS + 1, std::vector<int>(MAX_DIVS + 1)}; 
    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>> m_param_st{MAX_DIVS + 1, 
            std::vector<std::vector<double>>(MAX_DIVS + 1, std::vector<double>(2))};
};
```

Comment: Yes, true, but the problem is still there. Though this way is better and recommended, but still can't have, 100000 of them in std::vector

Comment: It has nothing to do with the stack. You allocate `100000 * (51 * sizeof(std::vector<int>) + 51 * 51 * sizeof(int) + 51 * 51 * sizeof(std::vector<double>) + 51 * 51 *  51 * 2 * sizeof(double))`, do you have free memory ~205GB?